# Combining Elastic Search Queries

Tags: elasticsearch, match, fuzzy-search

I am using Elasticsearch and would like to combine 2 sets of query results into one query if possible.

I am using 3 fields for this.

First query is that I want just 5 results that have the field "featured" to be the value "1" but also fuzzy match the term "seo" in fields "title" and "description".

Then I want the remainder of results that just fuzzy match the term "seo" in fields "title" and "description" with the featured to be "0".

I am unsure if the limit 5 can be used. Any ideas anyone. If you need more information please let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Consider merging this two queries into one [bool query](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html#query-dsl-bool-query) with "should" clause.